# Schrödinger equation with complex potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation

In 1 dimension what is the solution of the Schrödinger equation with potential

$$ V(x) = V_r + i V_i $$

Potentials are constant.

Answer (score 2):

The Hamiltonian
$$H=T_{\text{kin}}+V_r+iV_i$$ 
will not be Hermitian as
$$(iV_i)^*=-iV_i.$$

Technically, you can make an ansatz
$$\Psi(x,t)=A\int\text{d}k\ \hat\Psi(k)\ \text e^{i(kx-\omega(k)t)}.$$

plug it into the differential equation and find

$$\omega(k)=\frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}+V_r+iV_i,$$
or
$$\hbar k=\pm\sqrt{2m(E-iV_i)},$$
where $E$ is some real number/numbers. You also want a boundary condition.

(As a vague remark, modelings of complex energies, which necessarily turn a phase like $\text e^{-i\omega}$ into something like the descending expression $\text e^{-\omega'}$, are associated with decay. But again, a particle that vanishes in time like that is probably not what you want to talk about.)

Comment: Comment to the answer(v2): It should be stressed in the answer that the wavenumber $k$ is a manifestly _real_ variable, not complex. Therefore the corresponding energies $E_k\equiv \hbar\omega_k$ are not real but _complex._

Comment: as a comment i heard that a Schroedinguer equatio with the potential $ V(X) = ix^{3} $ may have ALL the energies real :)